# If/When the site leaves beta, will there be an option to migrate questions?

Tags: feature-request

Like what happens on superuser/stackoverflow/etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migration paths will be defined when the sites graduate out of public beta.

In the meantime, the best course of action is to close the question and re-ask it on the site you believe it belongs on.